# Discretization simulation of a Wiener Process

Tags: r, stochastic-process, discretization

I got some problems with this homework which I have totally no idea, never got into this field before and I really need some help.

First, we have a wiener process like

[image]

Which means the probability of the process drops beneath -3 within the time interval [0,1].

Now the thing is **we have to simulate the process by discretize it.**

**1.Suppose we first discretize the process by 100 points and simulate 10,000 process in this way.**

i.e., W(0.01), W(0.02), …., W(1.00).

Note that W(t) – W(t-0.01) ~ N(0,0.01) independently.

**2.Using the data obtained at 1., we approximate**

[image]

**by**

[image]

**what is the relationship between this value and the real**

[image]

**(larger, equal to or smaller)?**

**3.Repeat 1. and 2. by cutting [0,1] into 10,000 points instead. Will the
 resulting probability increases or decreases?**

Comment: the only thing i know about is I can simulate wiener process by using BM function in Sim.DiffProc package.. that s all. I am so new that I dnt even know how to simulate a wiener process which has a min limit...guys plz help me orz

Comment: the answer of all these is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406590/discretization-simulation-of-a-wiener-process